# How to keep footer on the bottom without affected by position:absolute element

Tags: html, css

How do I keep the footer on the bottom without being affected by the position:absolute element. Right now, the footer's position is relative and apparently the box with absolute:position create its own stacking context and overflow the footer.
The html looks like below

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div style="position:absolute">
  </div>
</div>
<footer style="position:relative">
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question, along with any additional requirements: which browsers must you support? How flexible are you with editing your code (some people can't change their HTML)? As it stands this question is too broad, and somewhat unclear - both are grounds for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position absolute elements don't have dimension. (height & width).

So in order to stack correctly, you have to :

- give `height` for your absolute position element.
  or
- Add `margin-top` on your footer element based on your absolute position element height

Answer (score 0):

When you use position absolute it is absolute positioned to the nearest ancestor element which has relatively positioned. You can have your footer not disturbed by enclosing your absolute div inside a relatively positioned div.

If you don't want to do that change you can move the element using margins and left,right,top and bottom properties.